# Use a autoincrement with hibernate and Mysql that is not an Id so I can reset it with a trigger

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, auto-increment

I'm implementing a registry app in which each record is identified with a reference like 01/2016, 02/2016, ... and so on.
In my Entity class, I'm using

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private int year=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int numReception; // this field will reset each year with a trigger.
private String reference; // This field should look like "01/2016", filled by a trigger too.
```

The reference field will be filled by a trigger too as a combination : "**numReception/year**".

The problem is that hibernate won't auto-increment something that is not a primary key, and I can't use auto increment inside an embaddable composite key too.
**@prepersist** and **@postPersist** are not working eather because JPA callbacks won't work if you're using the Session API (to be used instead of  triggers).

Any solution to implement an auto increment ? any other suggestions ?

Comment: While I don't know how to do this from inside Hibernate, it *is* possible to use `auto_increment` on non-primary key columns. If this is an option for you, you could `alter table` manually to this effect.

Comment: What table engine do you use in mysql?

Comment: InnoDB, I'm generating the database schema through hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I used a composite key as **@embeddable** with two field id and year, 
and I set the id to be auto_increment using this SQL query as suggested by [geert3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201506/geert3)

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment;
```

Which I included inside a .sql file and added it to hibernate using the property

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">set_auto_increment.sql</prop>
```

so I can keep generating my DB using Hibernate.